Proving that the rank of the following matrix is $6$.
In my research work I have come across a matrix which has the rank equals to $6$. I begin defining my problem as follows: Let $P \in \{0,1\}^{7 \times 7}$ denote the right shift matrix defined by
$ P = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$
Let $\mathbf{1}_7$ denote the vector of all $1'$s, i.e.,
$
\mathbf{1}_7 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
1\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$
Let $V\in \mathbb{R}^{7\times 7}$ be a given matrix and let $ \mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2,\mathbf{v}_3,\mathbf{v}_4,\mathbf{v}_5,\mathbf{v}_6,\mathbf{v}_7$ represent the column vectors of the matrix $V$. Suppose that matrix $V$ is such that it satisfies the following matrix equations
$$V \mathbf{1}_7=\mathbf{0}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ (1)$$
$$\Bigg[\mathbf{v}_1\Big| P^1\mathbf{v}_2 \Big|P^2\mathbf{v}_3 \Big|P^3\mathbf{v}_4 \Big|P^4\mathbf{v}_5 \Big|P^5 \mathbf{v}_6 \Big|P^6 \mathbf{v}_7\Bigg]\mathbf{1}_7 = \mathbf{0}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
$$\Bigg[\mathbf{v}_1\Big| P^2\mathbf{v}_2 \Big|P^4\mathbf{v}_3 \Big|P^6\mathbf{v}_4 \Big|P^1\mathbf{v}_5 \Big|P^3 \mathbf{v}_6 \Big|P^5 \mathbf{v}_7\Bigg]\mathbf{1}_7 = \mathbf{0}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$
$$\Bigg[\mathbf{v}_1\Big| P^3\mathbf{v}_2 \Big|P^6\mathbf{v}_3 \Big|P^2\mathbf{v}_4 \Big|P^5\mathbf{v}_5 \Big|P^1 \mathbf{v}_6 \Big|P^4 \mathbf{v}_7\Bigg]\mathbf{1}_7 = \mathbf{0}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (4)$$
$$\Bigg[\mathbf{v}_1\Big| P^4\mathbf{v}_2 \Big|P^1\mathbf{v}_3 \Big|P^5\mathbf{v}_4 \Big|P^2\mathbf{v}_5 \Big|P^6 \mathbf{v}_6 \Big|P^3 \mathbf{v}_7\Bigg]\mathbf{1}_7 = \mathbf{0}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (5)$$
$$\Bigg[\mathbf{v}_1\Big| P^5\mathbf{v}_2 \Big|P^3\mathbf{v}_3 \Big|P^1\mathbf{v}_4 \Big|P^6\mathbf{v}_5 \Big|P^4 \mathbf{v}_6 \Big|P^2 \mathbf{v}_7\Bigg]\mathbf{1}_7 = \mathbf{0}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (6)$$
Given that the matrix $V$ is not all-zero matrix then the rank of $V$ is $6$. I have run simulations and found that any such non-zero matrix $V$ that satisfies the above equations has rank $6$. However,I am not able so prove it mathematically nor do I get any references that deals with such kind of matrices.
I think proof should be followed in the following way:
Since $V \mathbf{1}_7=\mathbf{0}$, rank of $V$ can't be equal to $7$. Now, for any vector $\mathbf{u}$ which is orthogonal to $\mathbf{1}_7$, if we equate $V \mathbf{u}=0$, then it should lead to some sort of contradiction. I am not able to see how we get to a contradiction. Can somebody help me in proving that the matrix $V$ has rank $6$?

Surely with $v_1 = (1,...,1)^T$ and $v_k = -{1 \over 6} v_1$ for $k > 1$ would satisfy the equations but has rank $2$?

Running numerical simulations for rank is almost pointless in most cases.

@copper.hat ; thanks, but with your answer rank is $1$. May I ask, the matrix $V$ will always be rank $1$?

I don't understand your what you are asking. This is a counterexample to the statement that $V$ must have rank $6$.

In view of your other questions on math SE, perhaps it is worth asking: Are these matrices and vectors over the real field $\mathbb R$ or the binary field $\mathbb F_2$??
